Formatting referenced text of description list items
This is basically a follow-up to this question.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\let\orgdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
    \let\orglabel\label
    \let\label\@gobble
    \phantomsection
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1\unskip}%
    \let\label\orglabel
    \orgdescriptionlabel{#1:}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item [{Continuous functions\label{cf}}] A function $f$ ...
    \item [{Lipschitz continuous functions\label{lf}}] A function $f$ ...
    
\end{description}

Let $f$ and $g$ be \ref{cf} and $h$ be a \ref{lf}.
\end{document}


What is the best way to fix the formatting of those Refs? Is there a way to have options so that based on context one could choose to go with a referenced text that starts with small caps or it is singular not plural?
P.s. I am using Lyx, so I hopping for a solution would not involve much ERT, but any solution is appreciated.

I wouldn't do that through label and ref. Use one of the glossary packages (e.g. glossaries or acro)
